# Moving a split Vim window to the other half of the screen

Tags: vim

Let's say we have 3 buffers (A, B, C) open in Vim arranged as follows

```
-----------------------------------------
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|        A         |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|------------------|          B         | 
|                  |                    |     
|                  |                    | 
|         C        |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
-----------------------------------------
```

and we want to rearrange it as

```
-----------------------------------------
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |         B          | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
|         A        |--------------------| 
|                  |                    |     
|                  |                    | 
|                  |         C          | 
|                  |                    | 
|                  |                    | 
-----------------------------------------
```

I know I can do this by closing C and reopening it after splitting B. Is there a simple way to do this where I don't have to close buffers and I can rearrange the windows directly?

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer, faster, at vim.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: It's unclear what the pattern is here. Assume there is a shortcut for doing what you want. Would the shortcut move c from the left to right? If you press it again, does it move C back to the left side? Does it move B to the top half of A? If you can clearly define what behavior you'd want out of this shortcut, that would help greatly.

Comment: If you're asking what I want, it would be something like [how the i3 Windows Manager](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_tree) manages things. So in your specific example, if I press the same shortcut when it's in the second state it would then split the screen into three vertical windows. Based on the answer given, though, it doesn't look like Vim has this functionality built in.

Comment: If you can pin down the algorithm, you can customize your own shortcut for doing this.

Comment: Agreed with @wxz. With all the stuff under `:help window-functions` and `:help window-moving` as well as a solid algo, you should be able to write exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't "close" the *buffer* C, only the *window* that displays it.

Vim has dedicated normal mode commands for:

- switching a window and the next one in a row or column,
- rotating the whole window layout,
- pushing a window to the far top, far right, far bottom, and far left,

but it doesn't have one for moving a window to an arbitrary point so, assuming the window you want to move has the focus, the command should look like this:

```
:q|winc w|sp c
```

which is not too shabby. You might be able to find a plugin that provides the level of control you are after on https://www.vim.org.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.